# Scam someone out of something

Tags: grammar, verbs

I read it on the following sentence:

> ... to scam people out of their cash.

I didn't find any entries on "scam out of" as a phrasal verb in online dictionaries.

Should I interpret "scam" and "out of" as separate constructions here?

Like "to scam" people until they run "out of their cash"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I would interpret "out of" as its own thing, since it's used with other verbs, all with similar meanings:

- [Bamboozle someone out of something](https://wordwarriors.wayne.edu/list)
- [Bilk someone out of something](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/bilk)
- Bullshit someone out of something
- Charm someone out of something
- [Cheat someone out of something](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/cheat_1)
- [Con someone out of something](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/con+out+of)
- Dupe someone out of something
- Finesse someone out of something
- Hustle someone out of something
- Persuade someone out of something
- [Swindle someone out of something](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/swindle)
- Talk someone out of something
- [Trick someone out of something](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/cheat_1)

"Out of" even has its own definition in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/out%20of):

> used as a function word to indicate exclusion from or deprivation of